# Azure Devops Pipeline keeps failing NuGetCommand

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core

As the title said, it shows me this error

> The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(NU1607: Version
>   conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to resolve this issue.
>   ManagementStudio (>= 1.0.0) -> ManagementStudio.Data (>= 1.0.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 2.2.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (>= 2.2.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.2.0)   ManagementStudio (>=
>   1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.0). Errors in
>   d:\a\1\s\ManagementStudio\ManagementStudio.csproj
>       NU1607: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery. Reference the package directly from
>   the project to resolve this issue.
>        ManagementStudio (>= 1.0.0) -> ManagementStudio.Data (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (>= 2.2.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures (>= 2.2.0) ->
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.2.0)
>        ManagementStudio (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App (>= 2.1.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery (>= 2.1.0).) Packages failed to restore

I'm really confused as I tried to reference Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery directly in ManagementStudio but the same error still happens.

This is what I referenced in ManagementStudio

```
<PackageReference Include="bootstrap" Version="4.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.1" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

This is what I referenced in ManagementStudio.Data

```
<PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.1">
```

What else should I reference? The errors only get worse when I add on more references. E.g. asking for more specific items aside from antiforgery.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your `netcoreapp` version. You are referencing `2.2.0` libraries from your `Data` project, but judging from the error, your application is targeting `netcoreapp2.1`.

I suggest upgrading this to `netcoreapp2.2` or referencing `2.1.x` libraries, since those versions match.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. My Data project is targeting 2.2 also though.